# Return html and php from method in php object coding

Tags: php, object

I have created an object (one of my first working ones) in PHP.  I have a need to return the following code several times on a page......

```
    <?php while($section = mysql_fetch_array($section3)){ ?>
           <tr width='150'>
             <td><?php echo $section['EmProSectName'];?></td>
             <td><?php
    echo $sect2->FindStatusRow($_SESSION['cEmployee'], $section['idEmProSect']);

    ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $section['EmProSectBTN']; ?></td>
           </tr>

           <?php 
  $checkSect = $sect2->checkSubSection($section['idEmProSect']);
  if($checkSect==1){

     $subSect = $sect2->getSubSection($section['idEmProSect']); 
     while($sect = mysql_fetch_array($subSect)){
  ?>
           <tr>
             <td class="indent30"><?php echo $sect['EmProSectName'];?></td>
             <td><?php

            echo $sect2->FindStatusRow($_SESSION['cEmployee'], $sect['idEmProSect']);
    ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $sect['EmProSectBTN']; ?></td>
           </tr>

           <?php }?>
           <tr>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
           <?php  
        } 
    }  ?>
```

I was going to write a method to return this above statement.  Something along the lines of

```
   public function showEmployProcessresult($sectName){
      // here would be the table statement
   }
```

however Im not sure how to write my block in the middle and then return it properly.  can someone please show me how?

Comment: Instead of echoing php in the middle of html elements, why don't you create a string joined by those php elements, and then echo out the entire string. Then in your `showEmployProcessresult()` function, you would generate and return the string, then echo it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, I removed the $sectName variable as it is not used and combined the empty td together.

```
public function showEmployProcessresult(){

         $block = '';

         while($section = mysql_fetch_array($section3)){

           $block .= '<tr width='150'>';
           $block .= '<td>';
           $block .= $section['EmProSectName']
           $block .= '</td>';
           $block .= '<td>';

           $block .= $sect2->FindStatusRow($_SESSION['cEmployee'], $section['idEmProSect']);

           $block .= '</td>';
           $block .= '<td>';
           $block .= $section['EmProSectBTN'];
           $block .= '</td>';
           $block .= '</tr>';

           $checkSect = $sect2->checkSubSection($section['idEmProSect']);

           if($checkSect==1){

             $subSect = $sect2->getSubSection($section['idEmProSect']); 

             while($sect = mysql_fetch_array($subSect)){

               $block .= '<tr>';
               $block .= '<td class="indent30">'.$sect['EmProSectName'].'</td>';
               $block .= '<td>';

               $block .= sect2->FindStatusRow($_SESSION['cEmployee'], $sect['idEmProSect']);

               $block .= '</td>';
               $block .= '<td>'.$sect['EmProSectBTN'].'</td>';
               $block .= '</tr>';

           }

           $block .= '<tr>';
           $block .= '<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>';
           $block .= '</tr>';
        } 
    }

    return $block;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome! Enjoy your time with php objects, it can get quite fun :)